# FireStore Database set never calls OnSuccessListener or OnFailureListener

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The Firestore database `set()` does not call `OnSuccessListener` or `OnFailureListener` and don't writes the data to the database online!

As you see in the code first I get the instanceID via `getInstanceId()` and this is working because I see the log statements.

But the Firestore database is never executed. I don't see any data in my database and the both methods are not called either.

No error message in the log.
I don't get it what's the problem here without any error message :-(

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(instanceIdResult -> {
        if(instanceIdResult == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Firebase Instance Id Result is null!");
            HyperLog.e(TAG, "Firebase Instance Id Result is null!");
            return;
        }

        String mToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        HyperLog.e(TAG, mToken);
        Log.e(TAG,mToken);
        Log.e(TAG,"ID is" + instanceIdResult.getId());

        db.collection(C_USERS).document(eMail).collection(C_DEVICES).document(instanceIdResult.getId())
                .set(deviceInfo)
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Success!");
                    callBack.onAddUpdateTokenSuccess();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    //noinspection Convert2MethodRef
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failure!");
                    callBack.onAddUpdateTokenFailure(e);
                });
```

I test this on a real device with debug build and this device has internet (Mobile and WiFi).

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem is a not allowed API in the Google Cloud Console.
After digging deeper into the logs I have seen that "FireStore" writes this line:

```
Requests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked.
```

Now I have added `Token Service API` to the allowed API's and it is working.
Both callbacks are now called successfully and the document is also written.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your API is allowed or not in the Google CLoud Console